# JPA - "java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated" when trying to persist Date field

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm using NetBeans IDE with Glassfish server, making web-service using JPA. My MySQL DB have `YEAR` field called `enlisted`, which is represented by `Date` in Java code.

`enlisted` is defined like this:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "enlisted")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date enlisted;
```

My web-service method is:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "addGroup")
    public StudGroup addGroup (
            @WebParam(name = "cd") String cd,
            @WebParam(name = "enlisted") String enlisted) throws ParseException {

        StudGroup group = new StudGroup();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        Date date = df.parse(enlisted);

        group.setCd(cd);
        group.setEnlisted(date);
        em.persist(group);
        return group;
    }
```

When I'm trying to test this method, I see this exception on Glassfish log:

```
Warning:   Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'enlisted' at row 1
Error Code: 1265
Call: INSERT INTO stud_group (cd, enlisted) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(courses.StudGroup[ id=null ])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:962)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:631)
...
```

As I've already mentioned, in MySQL `enlisted` is defined as `YEAR`. I am thinking this could cause this behavior, but when I'm trying to retrieve data everything works fine. For example:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getGroup")
    public GroupsList getGroup(@WebParam(name = "groupCd") String groupCd, @WebParam(name = "enlisted") String enlisted) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
        Date date = df.parse(enlisted);
        List<StudGroup> list = em.createNamedQuery("StudGroup.findByCdAndEnlisted").setParameter("cd", groupCd).setParameter("enlisted", date).getResultList();
        return new GroupsList(list);
```

This code works as intended. 
I've also tried formatting it as "yyyy-MM-dd", but still no effect.
Have searched for similar problems, but most of them happened either because of real SQL data truncation or because of wrong `ENUM` declaration. I think Date field is declared as it should be and none of this questions helped so I guess it is not duplicate.

How do I fix it? I have no idea where to look for now. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Following up on your guess that the `YEAR` type declartion in MySQL causes the problem, you could try to use an attribute converter for debugging or even solving the problem (`@Convert`, cf. [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html) and [example usage](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Converters_.28JPA_2.1.29)). I suggest you first check the value (and type) you get back from the DB and then try to modify the value/type to be written back accordingly.

Comment: Just a guess… This may be a feature, not a bug. The `YEAR` type according to [this doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html) is certainly not directly compatible with a SQL `DATE` type. Apparently MySql is extracting the year number from the SQL `DATE` and using that number as the value as the INSERT value of type MySQL `YEAR`. Obviously the rest of the SQL `DATE` is being ignored, so MySql is responsible in informing you that some data was lost (ignored), that lost data being the month number and day number. I suggest changing your code to feed in a proper YEAR input value.

Comment: @BasilBourque, you were right. Changing it to DATE helped.

Comment: Also, @Hein, thank you for advice, I'm kinda new to EJ and have issues with debugging, this knowledge can definitely help me in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with the help of [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque) I've actually solved this issue. It was right thing to mention that, according to [this doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html) `YEAR` is not actually SQL-standart type, and, as JPA, provided by EclipseLink, works only with pure SQL standart. Counting that, `YEAR` is MySQL-dependent type, so I've just changed it to `DATE` - and it finally worked.

Although I haven't tried it, there's also a possibility that creating [Native Query](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Native) could've helped to resolve it to, but this is objectionable decision as JPA was designed to be DB-independent (if we're talking about SQL-standart DBs).